# Exported mesh is a different shape than my mesh in blender

Tags: modeling, game-engine, unreal-engine

My mesh inside of blender looks normal and has all straight edges,: [image]

but when I export it, the edges are moved and multiple faces are intersecting: [image]

My export settings don't seem to be wrong and im not editing the mesh afterwards at all and  reexporting didn't work: [image]

Comment: try editing your mesh, selecting all the vertices and using 'merge by distance' (shortcut: type M and select 'merge by distance from the menu').  You may have duplicate verts.  You may also have interior faces.

Comment: as Marty says...we assume your model hasn't clean geometry. So if you wanna be sure...provide your blend file and we can check it - else we can just guess.